# Group morphism or group homomorphism?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I apologize for my question that might sound stupid, but i noticed that my lecturer in abstract algebra course uses always "group morphism" instead of "group homomorphism". In the books i see it written group homomorphism.
Do these two words mean the same or is there any difference? I am wondering because he's the only one i've heard using morphism. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes I believe your professor is using those terms interchangeably.

Comment: A "morphism" in general is usually agreed to be a map that preserves whatever structure of interest.  So a morphism of groups is a group homomorphism, while a morphism of topological spaces should continuous, etc...

Answer (score 1):

"Morphism" is a more general term that applies in any [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory); a morphism in the category of groups is called a group homomorphism. So yes, your lecturer is most certainly using both words interchangeably.

Comment: You can also speak of "homomorphism" in any category. In fact, the notation $Hom(X,Y)$ suggests that it is the canonical term.

Comment: @CaptainLama: you are quite right that the notation $Hom(X, Y)$ and the term hom-set are standard, but "homomorphism" is not the canonical term in category theory: the elements of hom-sets are  almost always referred to as "morphisms" or "arrows". E.g., see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_functor.